# pulling custom rankings in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

can someone explain this script to me. It is supposed to pull specific rankings in Google however, i am unsure how this replace function is working. What does "m," "key," and "value" come from?

Basically what I don't understand is how the ranking data is being collected from this script.

```
function rankingsPush()
{
var url = String(document.referrer);

// confirm they came from G
if (url.indexOf ("google.") !=-1)
{   

var urlVars = {};
var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value)
{
urlVars[key] = value;
});

// Push to GA Custom Variables
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', '1', 'Rankings', urlVars["cd"], 2]);

// Return the ranking in case
// you dynamic targeting based on ranking

return urlVars["cd"];

}
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, this has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google send the position of the result for a keywords in the search result page with the page referrer. The referrer is accessed in javascript via document.refererrer.

The referrer is then parts - for details look at the documentation for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), the callback for replace receives several parameters (match, submatch etc.) if tge first parameter to replace is a regular expression. In this case it extracts the query parameters als key/value pairs from the referring url and stores them in an array with the names of the query parameters as keys and the values as value.

So, the ranking is send by Google in the referring url and the "m," "key," and "value" parameters in the callback are return values from the regular expression that is used in the replace function.